# Errors when downloading snowfall and surface precipitation data from ERA-Interim

Tags: download, netcdf

I was using the python script to download some parameters from ERA-Interim reanalysis dataset. It worked fine with all other parameters except surface snowfall and total precipitation. It gives the error

**ecmwfapi.api.APIException: u'ecmwf.API error 1: ERROR 6 (MARS_EXPECTED_FIELDS): Expected 62, got 0'**

I checked on their website and the data should be totally available. I don't what the problem is here. Below is the script for downloading snowfall data. Please let me know if anything goes wrong. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import calendar
from ecmwfapi import ECMWFDataServer
server = ECMWFDataServer()

def retrieve_interim():
    """
   A function to demonstrate how to iterate efficiently over several years and months etc
   for a particular interim_request.
   Change the variables below to adapt the iteration to your needs.
   You can use the variable 'target' to organise the requested data in files as you wish.
   In the example below the data are organised in files per month. (eg "interim_daily_201510.grb")
"""
yearStart = 1984
yearEnd = 1989
monthStart = 1
monthEnd = 12
startDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (yearStart, monthStart, 1)
lastDate = '%04d%02d%02d' % (yearEnd, monthEnd, 31)
target = "sf_daily_%04dto%04d.nc" % (yearStart, yearEnd)
requestDates = (startDate + "/TO/" + lastDate)
interim_request(requestDates, target)

def interim_request(requestDates, target):
    """
    An ERA interim request for analysis pressure level data.
    Change the keywords below to adapt it to your needs.
    (eg to add or to remove  levels, parameters, times etc)
    Request cost per day is 112 fields, 14.2326 Mbytes
"""
server.retrieve({
    "class": "ei",
    "stream": "oper",
    "type": "an",
    "dataset": "interim",
    "date": requestDates,
    "expver": "1",
    "levtype": "sfc",
    #"levelist": "1000",
    "param": "sf",
    "target": target,
    "time": "00/12",
    "grid": "0.75/0.75",
    "format": "netcdf"
})
if __name__ == '__main__':
    retrieve_interim()
```

Answer (score 2):

In ERA-interim (http://apps.ecmwf.int/datasets/data/interim-full-daily/levtype=sfc/), snowfall and precipitation are only available as *forecast* product, not as *analysis* product. In the above link, if you tick the box 0 for step, you will find the precipitation and snowfall show up as grey (meaning not available).

Also see Table 9 in https://www.ecmwf.int/sites/default/files/elibrary/2011/8174-era-interim-archive-version-20.pdf. Precipitation and snowfall is accumulated from the beginning of each forecast. I would suggest you to go to the first website, click precipitation and snowfall for one month, click `view MARS request` and get a template how the mars request should look like.

[image]

Comment: It fixed my problem well! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Don't forget that you will need to add the two 12 hour steps together to get the daily total, cdo daysum will do the trick, but then you also need to shift the timestamp, otherwise the date will be off as it points to the "end" of the forecast step and not the beginning...    this is now avoided on ERA5 (get it also from Copernicus C3S) where they post-process hourly rainfall outfall as a non accumulated value.  Ps: you should upvote and "accept" the answer from Packard CPW if it helped... voting credits are the currency of stackexchange ;-)